# Stylized p strong before ul

Tags: css

I have two questions.

I have got a problem when I have an h2 before a p. 
I tried this :

```
h2 + p {
margin-top: 0
}
p + h2 {
margin-bottom: 0 
}
```

But when I have many h2 + p in the same page. The first h2 + p elements are not stylized. Its strange.

Then, how to stylize a `<p><strong>my text</strong></p>` before an `<ul>` ?

```
ul + p > strong {
margin-top: 0
}
```

That's don't work :-/

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a previous sibling selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: If you show us the **actual** structure we might be able to help. At the moment we have no way of finding out wht your selector is not working.